# Parse exported bookmarks file with ColdFusion

Tags: regex, parsing, coldfusion

I need to parse a list of bookmarks exported from a browser like Chrome, Firefox and IE. Maybe even google etc.

I played around and did something like this `reMatchNoCase("(<h3)(.*?)(</dl>)",myfile1)` loop. Then I use `reMatchNoCase("(<dt[>])(.*?)(</a>)",i)` within the `h3`/`dl`
tags, and then a lot of cleanup, but its really not reliable.

The thing is that they have categories using `h3` tags surrounded by `dl` tags and then the bookmarks in that. I can't just parse all URLs since I want to get the categories as in the browser.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

if it is XHTML, use XPath

if it is not, it wouldn't be easy.  Search https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parse+html

can you consider using a hybrid approach, parse with jQuery on client side first and post to CF?

Comment: FF3 does not save valid XHTML.  Looks like a subset of HTML 3 or thereabouts.  Internally labeled a "Netscape Navigator" file.

Comment: maybe this helps? http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/bookmarks/Bookmarks.java